# Which incoming port is required by JIRA's outgoing (SMTP) e-mail functionality?

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, smtp, jira

I have a JIRA 6.3.15 installed on an Ubuntu 14.04 in a VirtualBox VM. The host system for VirtualBox also is an Ubuntu 14.04. I configured JIRA to use SSL (as described here https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Running+JIRA+over+SSL+or+HTTPS ), set up a custom HTTPS port in JIRA's server.xml file, added a forwarding rule for that port in the VM configuration and opened the port in the host's firewall. All of this works fine.

Now I'd like to have JIRA send notification e-mails. I added an SMTP server to the JIRA configuration. This also works fine as long as I have the host system's firewall turned off (i.e. accept all incoming packets). But when the host firewall's default action for incoming packets is set to „Drop“, sending out e-mails from JIRA inside the VM over SMTP fails. The connection test fails with an UnknownHostException.
The host firewall's default actions for outgoing and forwarded packets is „Accept“.

So apparently some port for incoming packets needs to be opened in the host system for the JIRA e-mail functionality to work. Could anyone point me to which port this is? I have already tried 465 as both destination and source port without success, and I couldn't find any documentation on this.

Comment: `UnknownHostException` makes me think about a DNS issue with the SMTP server you should have defined. DNS uses port 53. Also you can try standard SMTP port 25.

Comment: TCP and UDP port 53 for DNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found it: First of all, the issue was not JIRA-specific, but just any DNS lookup from the guest or host failed. The root cause of this was the host firewall missing rules to accept all incoming packets belonging or related to already established connections. This applies to all ports, not just 53, as port 53 is the incoming port on the DNS server, but the DNS server's answer can reach my server (aka the DNS lookup client) at any port.